# Moviepy subclip infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop, moviepy

I have a trouble dealing with subclip function.

subclip is totally okay for some duration, but in specific duration it makes infinite loop

My code is as it follows

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

file=pd.read_excel(r"E:\CCTV 구간반복.xlsx")
video=r"E:\0715.mp4"

myclip = VideoFileClip(video)
part=myclip.subclip(file['변환 시작'][7],file['변환 종료'][7])
part.ipython_display()
```

Here is the file referenced in subclip

[image: CSV File with values]

from duration 0 to 6, there is no problem,
but 7 to final it makes infinite loop for me....

my source video is chinese news video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvSmgSXPwP0&feature=youtu.be

thanks in advance
Good luck to you all

Answer (score 0):

Your code works here without any trouble. Instead of using `pd.read_excel`, I have called it with hardcoded values:

```
part=myclip.subclip(73,79)
```

which gives me a temp mp4 file a little over 1MB. I also tried the other values from your list. No infinite loop here, it works.

Maybe your input mp4 file is somehow corrupted? I downloaded this via `youtube-dl`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I`ll try again with new file